# 500 (Internal Server Error) with Laravel & Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I create Laravel PHP application in Docker. First I setup Laravel app using

```
laravel new laravelDockerApp
```

it creates successfully.I verify it's setup by built-in server

```
php artisan serve
```

Then setup Local environment with Docker

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - app
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
```

app.docker

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

web.docker

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www
```

vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` command. app & web containers up successfully.When I check app in Browser using

> localhost:8080

I got

> 500(Internal Server Error)

Please, can you help to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a solution. I set the permission on my Laravel app using:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage && sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: While this actually works, please see my comment for a different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189065/1038490 in case setting 777 on all these files doesn't sound very appealing.

Comment: wonderful(niu bi)

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not apply to you since you are using Nginx, but in my case I am using the `php:7.0-apache` as source image, so I made the Apache user the owner of my app's files.

In my Dockerfile I have:

```
...

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .

...
```

This solved the problem, so it could be worth trying, either modifying your Dockerfile or maybe Docker Compose has some option for user permissions when mounting volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, and the issue for me was that while I'd created my directory structure, I'd failed to copy the .env file from .env.example. Copying this and hitting the webpage gave me a page which had this in the top right corner:
[image]

Clicking "Generate App Key" resolved this issue for me, but it's probably worth giving the .env file a once-over to make sure it's not got some other unset variables you'll need!